# Match bitmap image from server via BiometricSDK with another bitmap image?

Tags: c#, biometrics

I have stored a bitmap image in a server and want to do matching through BiometricSDK with another image that I select. I have got no idea how to solve it. Here is my current code.

```
//Make finger print image get through SDK process
Boolean result = true;
var fprintsdk = new BiometricsSDK.FingerPrint.CFingerPrint();
var fprintresult = new BiometricsSDK.FingerPrint.CFingerPrint();

//get finger print image
fprintsdk.setFingerPrintImage(fprintsdk.getFingerPrintImage());

fprintresult.setFingerPrintImage(fprintresult.getFingerPrintImage());
FPrintImg.Image = fprintresult.getFingerPrintImageDetail();
FPrintImg.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

//Open window to select finger print image
var open = new OpenFileDialog();
open.FileName = string.Empty;
open.Filter = "BMP|*.bmp"; //open text file as default
open.Multiselect = false;

if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(open.FileName); //select image and store out
    string Constr = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = BankServer.mdb";
    OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection(Constr);
    Conn.Open();
    string sFingerPrint = "Select * from Server Where Hash = '" + ccinfo + "'"; //get data from server
    OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(sFingerPrint, Conn);
    OleDbDataReader read1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    while (read1.Read()) //loop all data
    {
        //(Problem Stuck over Here)
        if (read1["FingerPrint"].GetType() == bmp) //Comparison text file and database
        {
            Messagebox.show("Well Done");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: John Willemse, Thx alot

Answer (score 0):

I don`t know what SDK you are using. Therefore, you needs to search how to generate a template from this two images and match the two templates. Biometric match is not done with images directly but with templates.

If you tell us what SDK you are using maybe I can answer it better.